# webpage font weight is inconsistent on mobile view

Tags: html, css, iphone, ios7, fonts

on the desktop my [webpage](http://www.doronwolf.com/) looks normal, even when i shrink the browser window to iPhone 4 screen size,
but on real iPhone it looks like some letters, randomly, are bold and others are not!
[image]
i have looked thorough the [CSS](http://www.doronwolf.com/indexcss/style-old.css) [files](http://www.doronwolf.com/indexcss/reset.css) 
but I can't seem to find whats causing this 
could this be an iOS7 bug? is there a way to fix it?

Comment: Have you tried with another font ? Maybe this one doesn't handle font-weight very well

Comment: Have you tried to apply font-weight: normal; wherever you don't need the font to be bold?

Comment: yessss! it was a font problem, changed the font and now everything is fine